# Glassfish-5 log does not show in eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am unable to see the Glassfish log in the Eclipse console anymore. It worked fine a few days ago.

I am using Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) with Glassfish 5, OpenJDK 8 and Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

The only Error i get is:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Stopping GlassFish 5 [domain1]".
Can't find bundle for base name sun.util.logging.resources.logging, locale en_US
```

Also if I click on Glassfish -> View Log nothing happens.
The server starts without an exception. The server.log file is written normally.

I tried to reset the project to an older version and reinstalling Eclipse.
That changed nothing.

Comment: I am also getting same error for eclipse 2020 java version 11

Comment: Same issue for me with "Glassfish 3" dinosaur!

Comment: I have the same issue. Perhaps someone here found the solution? I posted the issue with more detail and some workaround I tried without success: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67540377/eclipse-2021-glassfish-tools-not-working-unnamed-module-cant-load-sun-util